# TableView only shows one cell - Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Right now, I am have 2 different cell types and my code switches between the 2 when a property called newMode is enabled. The code is below.

```
else if indexPath.row>1{
    let previousExpensesData = monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row - 1].modificationDate
        let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: expense.modificationDate as! Date) // Do not add above 'date' value here, you might get some garbage value. I know the code is redundant. You can adjust that.
        let previousDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row - 1].modificationDate! as Date)
        if day == previousDay {
            newMode2 = false
        } else {
            newMode2 = true
        }
    }

    newMode=newMode2
```

This is what declares the condition for the modes to be switched.

```
if newMode==true{
        cell2.isHidden = true
        cell.isHidden = false
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        cell.dateLabelBackground.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 31)
        cell.dateLabel.text = dateString
        cell.expenseName2.text = expense.name
        cell.expenseAmount2.text = finalDisplayed
        cell.expenseCategory2.text = expense.category
        cell.expenseCollection2.text = expense.collection
        if (expense.expense) {
            cell.expenseAmount2.textColor = UIColor.red
        }


        else if (expense.income){
            cell.expenseAmount2.textColor = UIColor.green
        }

        if (expense.cash) && (expense.expense){
            cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Expense Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.cash) && (expense.income){
            cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Income Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
            cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Income Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
            cell.cashOrCredit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Expense Icon")

        }
        return cell
    }
    else if newMode==false{
        cell.isHidden = true
        cell2.isHidden = false
        cell2.expenseName3.text = expense.name
        cell2.expenseAmount3.text = finalDisplayed
        cell2.expenseCategory3.text = expense.category
        cell2.expenseCollection3.text = expense.collection
        if (expense.expense) {
            cell2.expenseAmount3.textColor = UIColor.red
        }


        else if (expense.income){
            cell2.expenseAmount3.textColor = UIColor(red:0.49, green:0.83, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
        }

        if (expense.cash) && (expense.expense){
            cell2.cashOrCredit3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Expense Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.cash) && (expense.income){
            cell2.cashOrCredit3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cash-Income Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
            cell2.cashOrCredit3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Income Icon")

        }
        else if (expense.credit) && (expense.income){
            cell2.cashOrCredit3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Credit-Expense Icon")

        }
        return cell2

    }
    else {
        return cell
    }
```

This is what happens when the cells are switched. However the problem is, right now my cell only shows one item at a time. When I delete that item and refresh the view controller, it shows the other item. Why is not showing all the items in my array that I use to populate the view controller. This was happening before, but doesn't happen after I started the cell switching. What am I doing wrong?

```
let expense = monthlyExpenses[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in great confusion regarding cell and rows to achieve what you want. Declare two custom type or builtin type of cells.

1. In your numberofrowsForIndexPath method check the condition and return 
   the count of the cell
2. In your cellforRowAtIndexPath depending on your mode return respective cell depending on mode
3. Where you are changing mode call tableView.reloadData()

Comment: So do you mean the top bit of code should be in the numberOfRowsForIndexPath method?

Comment: It depends upon how you are actually deciding your mode